# Google play APKs supporting Android Wear must have a minimum SDK version of at least 23

Tags: android, google-play, wear-os, developer-console

I have tried to upload new Android wear app to google play developer console
and I've got the following message:

> Upload failed
>   APKs that use the 'android.hardware.type.watch' feature
>   must have minimum SDK version of at least 23, and this APK has 20. If
>   you are embedding a watch APK inside a phone APK, the phone APK does
>   not need to use the 'android.hardware.type.watch' feature.

my app is configured to sdk 20.
I need it to be available for android 5.1.
my app is designed for wear only and not for both wear and phone/tablets.

things I have tried and didn't help:

1.remove

```
android:name="android.hardware.type.watch"
```

-the app is abled to be uploaded but I couldn't run it on a virtual watch device,
it says:

> missing uses-feature watch, non-watch apks cannot be launched on a watch

2.instead of removing

```
android:name="android.hardware.type.watch"
```

I have tried changing it to:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.type.watch"
    android:required="false" />
```

-the app is abled to be uploaded but I couldn't run it on a virtual watch device,
it says:

> missing uses-feature watch, non-watch apks cannot be launched on a watch

3. tried changing the minimum sdk from 20 to 23
   -the app won't work on 20-22 sdk devices.

My manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.galepshtein.metronomewatch">

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.type.watch"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Is your app an Android App with embedded Watch APK or a Watch-only APK?

Comment: There won't be any watches below API-Level 23. They don't exist (afaik).

Answer (score 0):

There are no Android Wear devices with an API-Level below 23. You are not restricting the customer base when uploading the App with a minimum SDK Version of 23.

Comment: So How Can It Be? Maybe My App Is App With Ambedded Watch Apk? How Can I Know?

Comment: What does your manifest look like? If the App has an embedded Watch APK, only the Watch APK itself needs the uses-feature directive and sdkVersion 23+. You should know what kind of application you are creating.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation: https://developer.android.com/wear/preview/features/app-distribution.html

Comment: so on what os smartwatches like the lg g watch urban runs on if not android 5.1? how they can run apps if the minimum target is sdk 23?

Answer (score 0):

Android Wear 2.0 Developer Preview 4 has extensive documentation for your question, see the [App Distribution](https://developer.android.com/wear/preview/features/app-distribution.html) topic.

To paraphrase:

- Android Wear 2.0 apps need a minimum API level of 24
- If you want to use the old distribution model (of using an embedded APK), you may use API level 23

It seems like you want to distribute a standalone Android Wear 2.0 app, so you should set the API level to 24.

Also, you must set up targeting for watches by providing `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />` and mark the app as standalone (see [this](https://developer.android.com/wear/preview/features/app-distribution.html#specifying-app-as-standalone) part of the docs) by specifying `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.wearable.standalone" android:value="true" />`